# How To Update WPFToolkit AreaSeries Chart On Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am making WPFToolkit based Graph where i am trying to update AreaSeries  every time i click on a button.
I have implemented [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx) on my data class. but when i reload the data in the source object id doesn't updates in chart(target object)

the code is as below:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   static List<Ready4LOS> Ready4LOS = new List<Data.Ready4LOS>();





    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chart1.DataContext = Ready4LOS;
        InitChart();
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        var path = @"zxzxzxz.log";
        Ready4LOS.Clear();
        List<APISTATDataModel> daa = APISTATDataModel.GetFromFile(path, new string[] { "|" }, "Ready4TOS");

        List<APISTATDataModel> lastn = daa.GetRange(daa.Count - 10, 10);

        foreach (APISTATDataModel d in lastn)
        {
            Ready4LOS.Add(new Ready4LOS() { Case = d.Current_Count, Time = d.Current_Time });

        }

    }

    private void InitChart()
    {
        System.Windows.Data.Binding indi = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Case");
        System.Windows.Data.Binding dep = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Time");
        dep.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneWay;
        indi.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneWay;
        AreaSeries ares = new AreaSeries();
        ares.ItemsSource = Ready4LOS;
        ares.IndependentValueBinding = dep;
        ares.DependentValueBinding = indi;
        ares.Title = "Ready4LOS";

        DateTimeAxis dta = new DateTimeAxis();
        dta.Interval = 10;
        dta.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        dta.Title = "Time";
        dta.Orientation = AxisOrientation.X;
     // dta.Minimum = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-90);
      //  dta.Maximum = DateTime.Now;

        LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
        yaxis.Minimum = 0;
        yaxis.Interval = 2;
        yaxis.Title = "Case";
        yaxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
        yaxis.ShowGridLines = true;
        chart1.Axes.Add(yaxis);
        chart1.Axes.Add(dta);
        chart1.Series.Add(ares);



    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        chart1.UpdateLayout();

    }



}
```

}

the data model is here

```
    class Ready4LOS : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _case;
    DateTime _time;

    public int Case
    {
        get
        {
            return _case;

        }

        set
        {
            _case = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Case");
        }
    }

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get
        {
            return _time;
        }

        set
        {
            _time = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

It loads perfectly when it starts as i've called the LoadData() in the beginning. 
The problem is when i click on the refresh button it loads the data in the source object but the target object's data in not updated i.e. chart is not updated it remains the same as of initial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<Ready4LOS>`, not `List<Ready4LOS>`. `ObservableCollection<>` already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and also `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `Ready4LOS` may only be necessary if you're going to dynamically change values for `Case` and `Time` for existing `Ready4LOS` already in your collection.

[image]

Comment: Wow, i never knew that.. will definitely try out and let you know

Comment: thanks for taking time and helping me...specially for that jif you put up there.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.